# Drupal form throws error on submission

Tags: forms, drupal, session-variables, token

A drupal form throws the below error on submission. The form is loaded and immediatly submitted and user is not ideal on browser.

```
'This form is outdated. Reload the page and try again'
```

I am using two drupal nodes with a common database  and a web server(load balancer) but the above error seems to appear when the form is rendered from one app server and the submit request goes to the other app server.

I wanted to understand where are the form tokens stored, i am assuming in the database. The above message appears because the form token in both the cases is different and app server assumes that the request is not part of the same session.

Also I am using apc cache so not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The tokens are stored in the db/form cache, but is generated using the php session ID so as far as I understand it if you generate the form on one server, then submit to the other, it will regenerate the token when it checks it, using a different session ID so won't match - from `common.inc`:

```
function drupal_get_token($value = '') {
  return drupal_hmac_base64($value, session_id() . drupal_get_private_key() . drupal_get_hash_salt());
}
```

What are you using as the load balancer? You may need to look at enabling sticky sessions if you can.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your reply. The problem seems to resolved when I disable APC cache.But when  I just disable cache_form for APC it doesnot work.My form is part of a block.Question is  what would trigger this, as I though session id would be shared through the database,Also it doesn't happen when  I initially start hitting my website but when multiple browsers make request it throws this error after the APC cache starts getting filled up.

Comment: Is it possible the block is getting overly-aggressively cached? If it is caching the rendered block it will have a stale token in there. Do you have a cache_block full of forms?

Comment: Hey Andrew, Somehow the private key is different for me on the database and both the APC cache. could that be an issue.

Comment: You mean you have different values for the 'drupal_private_key' variable? If so then that would be messing up tokens, but don't really know how you would end up with different keys though. Have you had a look at drupal_random_bytes() in bootstrap.inc - it seems to use different generation methods depending on what is available. Could there be a difference between your two servers causing that value to be calculated differently?
Feels like I am starting to reach a bit far though, I might be out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue. A load balancer spreads traffic between two web nodes. Drupal would give me `This form is outdated. Reload the page and try again` every now and then. The error would happen when a form was generated on one web node but submitted to the other.

I started by looking at `drupal_validate_form` which (among other things) validates the submitted form against the form token stored in `$form_state['values']['form_token']`. Jump over to `drupal_valid_token` and then to `drupal_get_token`. The function `drupal_get_hash_salt()` turned out to return non-consistent results on the two servers.

For some reason, `$drupal_hash_salt` was set on only one of the servers. On the server which was not set, Drupal would fall back to generate a salt based on the database settings.

The issue was resolved by setting `$drupal_hash_salt` in `settings.php` to the same value.

Comment: And how are you setting this ?

Comment: It says so in the last paragraph. Settings.php